# LD_LIBRARY_PATH too long for launching SAMCEF with Ubuntu 14.04 & Bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, library-path

I am trying to use the SAMCEF FE solver from SAMTECH with `Ubuntu 14.04`.

I successfully installed the software and added the path of the executable to the $PATH variable. Now when I want to test the system I should be able to enter, in the bash shell.

```
$samcef bacon test
```

What i get back is the following:

> word too long

I had contact with the software installation experts and they told me that the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable is probably too long.

So I tried to unset the variable:

```
$unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and retried again

```
$samcef bacon test
```

and samcef successfully starts.

I already knew that $LD_LIBRARY_PATH is quite an extensive variable because I use it with other software to connect them to libraries like the intel compiler. I never heard of it being able to be too long with Ubuntu/linux. I also don't want to change the variable every time I want to run samcef because, well, it is used by other programs.

If someone would be able to shed some light in this matter (why I get these messages and a possible solution without tampering too much with current configuration), would be awesome.

Comment: How long is it: `echo ${#LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`?

Comment: it is 1020 characters long